# MySQL LIMIT and GROUP BY with use of IN?

Tags: mysql

I have a table ITEMS, which has the props id, site_id, frequency

So far i can list the items and order them by frequency from an array of id, using

```
SELECT * 
FROM items 
WHERE id IN(1549, 1550, 1635, 1637) 
ORDER BY site_id, frequency DESC
```

But i'd like to group my results by site_id with only one item that has the best (highest) frequency..

how do i do ?

Edit : I'd like to have the items that have the best frequency grouped by site_id (one result by site_id)

Comment: posting some sample data and the expected result would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select i.*
from (
    select site_id, max(frequency) as MaxFrequency
    from item
    where id in (1549, 1550, 1635, 1637)    
    group by site_id
) im
inner join items i on im.site_id = i.site_id and im.MaxFrequency = i.frequency
where i.id in (1549, 1550, 1635, 1637)
```

Note: This will give you more than one row per `site_id` if both have the same frequency.

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing the datatypes or sample data it sounds like you want this:

<strike>`select id, site_id, max(frequency)
    FROM items 
    WHERE id IN(1549, 1550, 1635, 1637) 
    GROUP BY id, site_id
    ORDER BY site_id, frequency DESC`</strike>

Or you can use a sub-query:

```
select i1.id, i1.site_id, i1.frequency
from items i1
inner join
(
   select site_id, max(frequency) mx
   from items
   WHERE id IN(1549, 1550, 1635, 1637) 
   group by site_id
) i2
   on i1.site_id = i2.site_id
   and i1.frequency = i2.mx
WHERE i1.id IN(1549, 1550, 1635, 1637)
```

Comment: Nope, i only want one result by site_id and with the best frenquecy, this gives me more than one result by site_id

Comment: @Eric I realized that before you commented, see my edit. This is why sample data would be helpful. :)

Comment: @Eric my second query is identical to the the accepted answer so I don't know why you say it is not working.

Comment: tested your query, no result, tested his query, good results, end of story

Comment: Ok, I hadn't checked the actual revisions.